# how to create variable containing the age of another row inside a common id in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6],
                   'rank' : [1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,1,2],
                   'age' : [20,2,30,28,4,26,3,22,23,1,34,29,56,25],
                   'sex' : ['female','female','male','female','male','female','male','female','male','male','male','female','female','female'],
                   'care' : [np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan]})
```

| id | rank | age | sex | care | new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 | female | NA | NA |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | female | NA | NA |
| 2 | 1 | 30 | male | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 28 | female | NA | NA |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | male | NA | NA |
| 3 | 1 | 26 | female | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | male | NA | NA |
| 4 | 1 | 22 | female | NA | NA |
| 4 | 2 | 23 | male | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | male | NA | NA |
| 5 | 1 | 34 | male | NA | NA |
| 5 | 2 | 29 | female | NA | NA |
| 6 | 1 | 56 | female | 2 | 25 |
| 6 | 2 | 25 | female | NA | NA |

Hello people, the above table contains the following variables:

- id : home identification number
- rank : ranking of the person within the household, e.g., 1 means head of household, 2 spouse 3 children
- age : age of the person
- sex : sex of the person
- care : contains the ranking of the person within the household to whom care services are provided

so I want to create a variable called new that contains the age of the person receiving care within the home. I am trying to do this in Python 3.8

I did this exercise in Stata with this command:

```
rangestat new = age, by(id) int(rank care care)
```

and also did it in rtudio like this:

```
df <- df %>%                             
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(new = age[match(care, rank)]) %>%
  ungroup
```

I hope I have made myself understood and also not cause inconvenience, I thank you in advance

Comment: Like the above commenter, I truly have no idea what you're asking.  What is the meaning of "new"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one liner:

```
result = pd.merge(
    df,
    df[['id', 'rank', 'age']].rename(
        columns={'rank': 'care', 'age': 'new'},
    ),
    how='left',
)
```

The result is exactly what you want:

```
>>> result
   id  rank  age     sex  care   new
0   1     1   20  female     2     2
1   1     2    2  female  <NA>  <NA>
2   2     1   30    male     3     4
3   2     2   28  female  <NA>  <NA>
4   2     3    4    male  <NA>  <NA>
5   3     1   26  female     2     3
6   3     2    3    male  <NA>  <NA>
7   4     1   22  female  <NA>  <NA>
8   4     2   23    male     3     1
9   4     3    1    male  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: I edited the post with some examples so that it is better understood what I want to do in python, thanks for your interest in helping me

Comment: @DarwinGalvis what is wrong with the answer that I already provided? It works, doesn't it?

Comment: I am working with a much larger data frame of 148.000 observations, I am going to test the answer to see if it works

Comment: It didn't work with the longest data frame I'm working with, thanks anyway dude

Comment: @DarwinGalvis You're not giving me any details on how my function fails. I can help you only if you provide me with some details about the failure

Comment: the problem is that in the longest data frame I'm working with there are ids (that is, homes) where nobody is cared for, so the care variable has many NAs, in the simple example that I uploaded, I put all the ids with at least one person who receives care, I do not know if it makes me understand. a command that performs the match would be better

Comment: @DarwinGalvis Please update your question with a more compete example (and the expected output) so that I can work on it

Comment: I just made friend, I changed the table a little, it is similar to what I am working with the long data frame

Comment: I was making a mistake when doing the merge, your input worked perfectly, thank you very much. If I would have liked to do it with a special command but just as great contribution dude

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this?

```py
new = pd.Series([2,np.nan,4,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan], name="new")
new_df = pd.concat([df, new], axis=1)
print(new_df)

"""
   id  rank  age     sex  care  new
0   1     1   20  female   2.0  2.0
1   1     2    2  female   NaN  NaN
2   2     1   30    male   3.0  4.0
3   2     2   28  female   NaN  NaN
4   2     3    4    male   NaN  NaN
5   3     1   26  female   2.0  3.0
6   3     2    3    male   NaN  NaN
7   4     1   22  female   NaN  NaN
8   4     2   23    male   3.0  1.0
9   4     3    1    male   NaN  NaN
"""
```

Comment: I think I get what you want now. The `new` column is to have the `age` value of the person in the same household `id`, for the person who is providing care, and N/A otherwise.

Comment: I edited my post with some examples in other programs to see if it is better understood what I want to do in python

Comment: I should clarify that I meant to say "the `new` column is to have the `age` value of the **_youngest_** person in the same household `id`". In any case, it looks to me like Riccardo's solution does what you want.

Comment: It's not _youngest_ it's the rank value associated to the value in care. `id 1 Care 2` corresponds to `id 1 rank 2` it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the age value. @JethroCao

Comment: @HenryEcker OP says age, and that's what you see from his sample data too.

Comment: exact Henry Ecker, it is not the youngest, it is to take the age if the variable care is associated with rank

Comment: The `care` column has a value, that value corresponds to a `rank` value in each group. OP is looking for the _associated_ age to that key value pair, It is not necessarily the _youngest_ person in the group although that seems to be the case in this instance.

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Comment: @HenryEcker you are correct, that's what i want to do in python i can't find a command to do it

Comment: The [self-`merge` approach above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239451/15497888) is the closest to the mutate approach in `R` and would be my approach in `pandas` as well.